# Laravel 5 belongsToMany() on custom table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using custom made tables. It is simple user role feature. But not using conventional Eloquent database schema style.

Table User

1. userId(PK)
2. userName (varchar)

Table Role

1. roleId (PK)
2. roleName (varchar)

Table userrole *pivot column*

1. userroleId
2. roleId
3. userId

Now I've Model User which has this method

```
    public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Role", "userrole", "roleId", "userId");
}
```

When I make call like this it gives error

```
$roles = App\User::where("userId", "1")->first()->roles;
dd($roles);
```

Error it displays is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `role`.*, `userrole`.`roleId` as `pivot_roleId`, `userrole`.`userId` as `pivot_userId` from `role` inner join `userrole` on `role`.`id` = `userrole`.`userId` where `userrole`.`roleId` is null)
```

Here's my humble request. Please don't suggest to change the table schema. I can't. I'm stuck with this.
Thank you!

Comment: Here's my humble response, Please follow the conventions unless you have a meaningful name for keys like `email`, `SSN` etc.

Comment: @Asim no need for such a response, i wish we all had the luxury of being able to always follow Taylor Otwell's conventions in every single project we work on, when you have to pick up shit in Zend Framework v1 and Codeigniter then you'll understand what it's like to be a professional web developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the primary key on your "userrole" model?

Laravel automatically assume that you're primary key is named `id`.

See this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Take a look at the primary key section:

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named `id`. You may define a `$primaryKey` property to override this
>   convention.

Try to override it at your `userrole` model like so:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'roleId';
```

Try to read all the doccumentattion carefully.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: this was helpful to me. Thanks.